# How to check if a div have a onclick event using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Does anyone know how to check if a div have a onCick event
let say i have a div

```
<div id="test" onClick={function123()}>
{childeren}
</div>
<div id="test">
{childeren}
</div>
```

so how to check if which div have onClick event?

a solution for this query so that i can ignore element that has onClick events

Comment: Is it a bad answer to say, "you click it"? -> I couldn't help myself.

Comment: Literal answer to your question: if `document.querySelector("div[onclick]")` is not null, then it has that attribute. But this does not check for other listeners added programmatically.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

below is the solution

```
nodeName.onclick === "function"
```

if the above solution is true
that means `div` has `onClick`
else it will be false

Comment: Well, that's not true. *Maybe* if you did `typeof nodeName.onclick === "function"` it would work, but it wouldn't account for events added the correct way, using `addEventListener`...